# Java 8: DateTimeFormatter based off of timezone

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, locale

I thought this would be easy, but I have had no luck in my research.

Using Java 8:

I am looking to parse a String representation of a date from a file into a long date.  Generally this would be as easy as creating a DateTimeFormatter object based off of a matching pattern and then calling parse on that object.

My problem is that the format changes based off of the locale that this file is generated in ie:

**NA/CHINA:** *MM/dd/yy hh:mm a*

**DE/UK**: *dd/MM/yy HH:mm*

**JAP:** *yy/MM/dd HH:mm*

Currently I have implemented a regex based solution that determines the format for the locales that are currently possible.  This works but I am looking for a better solution so that if a new timezone/locale is added this method does not need to be modified.

I was hoping I could create a formatter based off of a timezone tag (pulled from a different file) such as **EST,CEST,JST** etc. From what I have been able to find you can generate a formatter based off of a locale but I can't find a way of either generating a locale or a formatter from a timezone.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Haven't tried yet, but maybe [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#getLocalizedDateTimePattern-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.chrono.Chronology-java.util.Locale-) can help?

Comment: If the timezone you receive (JAP,DE) are java timezone formats, while constructing SimpleDateFormatter you can set that timezone and parse the date. Otherwise you may need to maintain mapping between incoming timezone & corresponding java timezone format to create a generic method.

Comment: @fge Thats one of the methods I was looking at, but it takes a locale not a timezone.

Comment: @Nambari unfortunately I don't see a SimpleDateFormatter constructor that takes a timezone argument... just a Locale

Comment: Well, that is pretty much expected, isn't it? I guess you'll have to build your timezone <-> locale map... Unless one exists already, I don't know

Comment: @fge, actually I didn't expect it.  I'm quite surprised the functionality is not built in especially in Java 8...

Comment: You need to use setTimeZone http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

Comment: @Nambari, thanks but that doesn't look like it will work.  From what I understand setTimeZone will set the timezone to be displayed if I include a timezone in my date pattern.  I'm looking to base my pattern off of the timezone (figure out the order of days/months/year etc.)  It looks like my best option is going to be a map as fge suggests.